# .NET-Core GoogleCloudMlV1PredictRequest Execture Method Returns null Response

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, google-cloud-ml-engine

In .NET-Core C#, I am using Googles ml API for interacting with the engine. The code I have for my predict method is here

```
string credPath = @".\appkey.json";
var json = File.ReadAllText(credPath);
PersonalServiceAccountCred cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

// Create an explicit ServiceAccountCredential credential
var xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new 
ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.ClientEmail)
{
    Scopes = new [] {
        CloudMachineLearningEngineService.Scope.CloudPlatform
    }
}.FromPrivateKey(cr.PrivateKey));

var service = new CloudMachineLearningEngineService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {
    HttpClientInitializer = xCred
});

ProjectsResource.PredictRequest req = new ProjectsResource.PredictRequest(service, new GoogleCloudMlV1PredictRequest {
    HttpBody = new GoogleApiHttpBody {
        Data = "{\"instances\": [{\"age\": 25, \"workclass\": \" Private\", \"education\": \" 11th\", \"education_num\": 7, \"marital_status\": \" Never - married\", \"occupation\": \" Machine - op - inspct\", \"relationship\": \" Own - child\", \"race\": \" Black\", \"gender\": \" Male\", \"capital_gain\": 0, \"capital_loss\": 0, \"hours_per_week\": 40, \"native_country\": \" United - States\"}]}"
}, "projects/{project_name}/models/census/versions/v1");

GoogleApiHttpBody body = req.Execute();
```

However, I'm getting this response back on the GoogleApiHttpBody object:

[image: All null fields in GoogleApiHttpBody response object]

Does someone know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the Google API and seeing requests coming through, I thought something might be wrong with the library. I've posted details on my own blog here: [.NET-Core GoogleCloudMlV1PredictRequest Execture Method Returns null Response](http://tylerfindlay.com/net-core-googlecloudmlv1predictrequest-execture-method-returns-null-response/)

What's happening is the GoogleApiHttpBody doesn't serialize the "instances" object where the :predict endpoint is expecting it. I figured that out when I read the stream and saw this response:

```
{"error": "<strong>Missing \"instances\" field in request body</strong>: {\"httpBody\":{\"data\":\"{\\\"instances\\\":[{\\\"age\\\":25,\\\"workclass\\\":\\\" Private\\\",\\\"education\\\":\\\" 11th\\\",\\\"education_num\\\":7,\\\"marital_status\\\":\\\" Never - married\\\",\\\"occupation\\\":\\\" Machine - op - inspct\\\",\\\"relationship\\\":\\\" Own - child\\\",\\\"race\\\":\\\" Black\\\",\\\"gender\\\":\\\" Male\\\",\\\"capital_gain\\\":0,\\\"capital_loss\\\":0,\\\"hours_per_week\\\":40,\\\"native_country\\\":\\\" United - States\\\"}]}\"}}"}
```

So, I simple changed my code as follows, and now I get the predict result back correctly

```
string credPath = @".\appkey.json";
var json = File.ReadAllText(credPath);
PersonalServiceAccountCred cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

// Create an explicit ServiceAccountCredential credential
var xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.ClientEmail) {
    Scopes = new [] {
        CloudMachineLearningEngineService.Scope.CloudPlatform
    }
}.FromPrivateKey(cr.PrivateKey));

var service = new CloudMachineLearningEngineService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {
    HttpClientInitializer = xCred
});

ProjectsResource.PredictRequest req = new ProjectsResource.PredictRequest(service, new GoogleCloudMlV1PredictRequest(), "projects/{project-name}/models/census/versions/v1");

string requestPath = req.Service.BaseUri + 
CloudMachineLearningEngineService.Version + "/" + req.Name + ":" + req.MethodName;
Task result = service.HttpClient.PostAsync(requestPath, new StringContent("{\"instances\": [{\"age\": 25, \"workclass\": \" Private\", \"education\": \" 11th\", \"education_num\": 7, \"marital_status\": \" Never - married\", \"occupation\": \" Machine - op - inspct\", \"relationship\": \" Own - child\", \"race\": \" Black\", \"gender\": \" Male\", \"capital_gain\": 0, \"capital_loss\": 0, \"hours_per_week\": 40, \"native_country\": \" United - States\"}]}"));
Task.WaitAll(result);

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = result.Result;

Task responseStreamTask = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Task.WaitAll(responseStreamTask);

string responseText = responseStreamTask.Result;
```

Comment: You're correct -- you need to send the raw request. In your example `toSend` is unbound, so I'm assuming there's a bug in the code as presented?

Comment: You're correct! I tried to clean it up for StackOverflow and didn't recompile. Thanks @rhaertel80